# Error getting declarated Culture from web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 Application. I use ninject for DI and WebActivator to setup the environment.

Inside the Start method, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture reads correctly from the web.config as "es-DO" which is the declared locale:

```
 public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        Bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);

    }
```

Inside the PostStart method where I set routes and minification bundles the locale changes to "en-US". Which I assume is the default locale

```
 public static void PostStart()
    {
        ValidationSettings.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes();
        GlobalFilterConfig.RegisterFilters();
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
```

Does anyone know why this happens? the BundleConfig.RegisterBundles method relies on the Culture information to load the corresponding javascript files.

Comment: Can you show your web.config file, particularly the globalization element?

Comment: <globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" uiCulture="es-DO" culture="es-DO" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />

Comment: That looks good. Could be an issue with WebActivator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it like this:

```
//Hack to set the culture again to the one defined on the web.config
        var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
        var section = (GlobalizationSection)config.GetSection("system.web/globalization");
        if(section != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(section.Culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(section.UICulture);
        }
```